# What is the scenario for activemq embedded broker going down?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Is it the lack of memory in activemq broker that may lead it to not work?

I know there are other ways that it could go down but I am specifically interested in lack of memory and how we can increase it?

What are the different properties for memory in `activemq` that we can use to manage them?

Comment: ActiveMQ has many, many memory-related settings. Can you make your question any more specific? What reason do you have to think memory will be a problem?

Comment: I got an error once saying activemq is out of memory. It may not be exactly same error. But something similar to that.

Comment: In my experience, usual reasons for ActiveMQ running out of memory (other than bugs) are to do with pre-fetch and paging. Pre-fetch is the number of messages buffered by the client, and defaults to 1000 regardless of message size. Paging is the number of messages buffered in memory -- again, independent of message size. Because these settings do not take into account message size, they usually have to be reduced if the messages tend to be large (Mb or more). Large numbers of concurrent clients can also be a problem. JVM heap and thread dumps will often give a good idea where the problem is.